# Refactoring functions/using return. C++

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble refactoring this code into functions. What exactly am I supposed to enter for return to complete these last two functions. They include loops with total and subtotal with multiple calculations based on what character is entered. I understand the first two, just return the variable declared.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std; // forgive me for being lazy!

double getPrice();
int getNumber();
double saleTotal(double getPrice, int getNumber);
void retail(double getPrice, int getNumber, double saleTotal);

const double TAX_RATE = .05;

int main()
{
   double myPrice = getPrice();

   int myNumber = getNumber();

   double getTotal = saleTotal(myPrice, myNumber);

   retail;

    return 0;
}

double getPrice()
{
    double price;
    cout << "Enter price $";
    cin >> price;
    return price;
}

int getNumber()
{
   int number;
   cout << "Enter number purchased: ";
   cin >> number;
   return number;
}

double saleTotal(double getPrice, int getNumber)
{
    char saleType;
    double total;
    double subTotal;

    cout << "Type W if this is wholesale purchase. \n"
        << "Type R if this is retail purchase. \n"
        << "then press return... \n";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get(saleType);

    if ((saleType == 'W') || (saleType == 'w'))
    {
        total = getPrice * getNumber;
        return total;
    }
    else if ((saleType == 'R') || (saleType == 'r'))
    {
        subTotal = getPrice * getNumber;
        total = subTotal + subTotal * TAX_RATE;
        return total;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error in the input...";
    }
}

void retail(double getPrice, int getNumber, double saleTotal)
{
    char saleType;

    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << showpoint << getNumber << " items at $" << getPrice << endl;
    cout << "Total bill $" << saleTotal;
    if ((saleType == 'R') || (saleType == 'r'))
    {
        cout << " includes sales tax.\n";
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: All variables are uninitialized in `total`. Reading them causes undefined behavior. I can't find the nested loops

Comment: I would suggest making `subTotal` and `total` functions that take a price, a number of items purchased, and a sale type as arguments and then returning the subtotal and total, respectively, and then calling them with the values you get after receiving user input. Currently, `subTotal` doesn't actually know what value to use for `myPrice` because that was set and returned by the `getPrice()` function and never passed to `subTotal`. (Actually, `subTotal` might not need the `saleType` parameter at all, since that only matters for the total...)

Comment: So now `retail` depends on `number`, `price`, `total`, and `saleType`, which need to be arguments to the function. (Strictly speaking, it can compute `total` from the other three.) Your implementation of `saleTotal` also needs to be cleaned up. You have the variables you pass in as function arguments, but then you also have a bunch of local variables that don't do anything and cause UB when they're read without being initialized.

Comment: I updated the code again just before I saw your comment. It seems I already did as you suggested however now I get no total or anything from the last function. Probably because I put it as void I'm guessing, however I do not know what I should be returning with the fourth function. Professor suggested void if there is nothing to return.

Comment: This: `retail;` is NOT a function call! You need parenthesis and parameters...

Answer (score 0):

As the name of the methods suggest, you need:

```
double subTotal()
{
  ...
  return mySubTotal;
}
```

and:

```
double total()
{
  ...
  return total;
}
```

However in the `total()` method, `saleType` variable is used **uninitialized**, as @ThomasSablik commented, which means that your code invokes **Undefined Behavior** (UB) here:

```
if ((saleType == 'R') || (saleType == 'r'))
```

since you are checking an uninitialized variable in the conditions of this if statement.

`subTotal()` also invokes UB for the same reason. Initialize the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your functions `subTotal();` and `total` don't know about `myPrice` and `myNumber` variables from `main()`.

You declare new variables with the same names, but they are NOT connected to the original ones.

You need to pass those variables from `main()` into oter functions.

Comment: If I recall, is that accomplished via adding the variable I need to pass along into the prototype? Such as double wholesaleTotal (double myPrice); ?

Comment: @unit5016 Correct, although in that case it would probably be `double wholesaleTotal(double myPrice, int myQuantity);` because it depends on both values.

Comment: Ah! Thank you, my brain was just stuck on a mental block of some kind, unable to see it.

Comment: After some fiddling, I'm now getting "too few arguments to function wholesaletotal" in my main () block.  I changed my prototype to double wholesaleTotal(double getPrice, int getNumber); and of course changed the header of the body of my function down below.

Comment: Now you have to call it: `wholesaleTotal(myPrice, myNumber);`

Comment: See I tried that already and its gives me another error "cannot convert 'double(*)()' to 'double' so I assumed that was wrong.

Comment: @unit5016 - please update the code in your question to its current state. You can't just "guess" a correct syntax...

Comment: I apologize, I'm new to the website I did not think updating the original code posted was promoted/expected. I believe I have solved that error the only thing is its still not carrying over the variables thus my totals are always $0. Current code added.